# Parameterized constructor in view model not working

Tags: wpf

I have one small issue.
in my view model parameterized constructor is not working. while debugging i observed that default constructor get hit but it never triggers my parameterized constructor.
How I can get my parameterized constructor working?

```
public EmployeeRequestViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IContextManager contextmanager):this()
    {
        _contextmanager = contextmanager;
        _eventAgg = eventAggregator;
        _eventAgg.GetEvent<EmployeeEvent>().Subscribe(EventTask);
    }

    public EmployeeRequestViewModel()
    {
        LoadEmpRequest();

    }
```

Comment: Is your framework supposed to call such a constructor or where is your calling code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no code which uses the parameterized constructor it will of course not be hit. Or if the code which does is never executed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing an event aggregator I will make the assumption that you are using Prism.

Prism's Unity is greedy. When you resolve a dependency, Unity will find the biggest constructor that it can resolve and then create the object using it. If you are only using the default constructor then I would check that you have registered the `IContextManager` type in the UnityContainer.